# Manipulating text in first column only?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, perl

Example Input:

```
foobar@example.com foo@example.com,bar@example.com
```

Example Output:

```
foobar@example.org foo@example.com,bar@example.com
```

So, in "normal" circumstances, it would obviously be easy to do something like:

```
sed 's/.com/.org/g'
```

But obviously in this case, I only want the suffix in the first column to be manipulated, I want the second column to be left untouched.

I don't mind what tool you propose to use. But I prefer it to available on a standard linux without needing further install (i.e. something like `sed` or `awk` or `perl` would be more preferable to `bobsobscuretoolthatneedsinstalling`).

Comment: Why not just leave off the "g" at the end of the `sed` command? Then it will only replace the first occurrence...

Comment: [I’m a simple man. I see columns, I think “awk”.](https://imgflip.com/i/2oprlk)

Comment: @twalberg What if the first column has no `.com` but the second does?

Comment: @NicHartley Valid point in general, in which case I would use something like the accepted `awk` solution. But, it doesn't match the supplied sample input, which may or may not mean anything...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ awk '{ sub("\.com$", ".org", $1); print }' <file
foobar@example.org foo@example.com,bar@example.com
```

This uses `awk` to substitute the text matched by `\.com$` with `.org` in the first whitespace-delimited field (only) of each line. The output will be space-delimited.

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to replace the first occurrence of `.com` with `.org`, all you need is the default behavior of sed's `s///` operator. Just don't use the `g` flag:

```
$ sed 's/.com/.org/' file 
foobar@example.org foo@example.com,bar@example.com
```

If you really want to only make the change on the first comma-defined field, so that if the first `.com` appears elsewhere in the line, it will remain unchanged, you can do something like:

```
$ perl -pe 's/^(\S+)\.com/$1.org/' file 
foobar@example.org foo@example.com,bar@example.com
```

Or, safer in case `com` occurs as a substring (e.g. `foo.common.net`):

```
$ perl -pe 's/^(\S+)\.com\b/$1.org/' file 
foobar@example.org foo@example.com,bar@example.com
```

Alternatively, in GNU sed:

```
$ sed -E 's/^(\S+)\.com\b/\1.org/' file 
foobar@example.org foo@example.com,bar@example.com
```

Or, portably (assuming the first field is defined by the first *space* and not a tab or other whitespace):

```
$ sed -E 's/^([^ ])\.com /\1.org /' file 
foobar@example.org foo@example.com,bar@example.com
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using `sed`, just use a regexp that can only match the first word of the line:

```
sed -r 's/^(\S+)\.com(\s+)/\1.org\2/'
```

In slo-mo, change:

1. a sequence of one or more non-spaces from the beginning (`^(\S+)`)
2. `.com`
3. a sequence of one or more non spaces (so that we can only match a final `.com`)

into:

1. the first sequence of non-spaces
2. `.org`
3. the sequence of spaces

Comment: Not using the `/g` doesn't prevent the substitution to occur in other items of the line if it doesn't happen on the first. And capturing the final `\s+` insures that we aren't replacing `.com` in the middle of a node id such as `some.commonname.com`.

Comment: Note that the use of PCRE requires GNU `sed`.

Comment: OP asked for "standard Linux" :)